# Eigen-Decomposition of Householder operator

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, computer-science, numerical-linear-algebra

Define the eigen decomposition of householder operator $H=I-2ww^*$ where $\vert\!\vert w\vert\!\vert=1$, **geometrically**! I know that the eigen-values are $[-1, 1 \dots 1]$ but I cannot understand about the eigen-vectors and in particular I cannot depict the solution, geometrically!

Can anybody possibly help me to understand it through drawing a geometrical interpretation?

Thanks alot

Comment: Well, the Housholder operator is just a reflection across the sub-space of all vectors orthogonal to $w$. Thus, $w$ is an eigenvector for the eigenvalue $-1$ and any non-zero vector perpendicular to $w$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $1$.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. But it is not yet clear for me geometrically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, $Hv=(I-2ww^*)v=v-2w(w^*v)$
Notice that $w^*v$ is the length of the perpendicular from the $v$ onto the orthogonal complement of $w$.[image: A 2-D case]

In the above image, $w=\left(\frac1{\sqrt2}, \frac1{\sqrt2}\right)$, it's orthogonal complement is the line $y=-x$, and $w^*v$ is the length of the line $VP$.
As can be seen in the image, $w(w^*v)$ is the vector $\overrightarrow{PV}$. Subtracting it twice from $v$ gives its image over the line $y=-x$. Thus, $H$ is a reflection map around the orthogonal complement of $w$.
Clearly, all the vectors lying perpendicular to $w$ remain as they are (and correspond to eigenvalue $1$), while the ones parallel to $w$ get inverted (and correspond to eigenvalue $-1$).